# QtCharts 2.0 "Invalid grouped property access"

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qtquick2, qtcharts

I have the following code:

```
            import QtQuick 2.0
            import QtCharts 2.0
            ...
            ChartView {
                id: testChart
                title: "Chart"
                width: parent.width
                height: parent.height / 3
                legend.visible: true
                legend.alignment: Qt.AlignRight
                legend.font.pixelSize: ScreenModel.dp(10)
                legend.font.bold: true
                antialiasing: true
                ...
            }
```

If I run this code on iPhone simulator it works fine, but when I run it on a real IPhone 4S, it crashes with the following log:

> qrc:/platform/common/qml/main.qml:461 Type TestPage unavailable
>   qrc:/platform/common/qml/page/TestPage.qml:727 Invalid grouped
>   property access
>
> ASSERT failure in QList::at: "index out of range", file
>   ../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qlist.h, line 478 program
>   received signal 6,
>   thread:321e1;qaddr:366e2ad0;00:00000000;01:00000000;02:00000000;03:00000000;04:06000000;05:dc296e36;06:e8260b03;07:fc441303;08:00000000;09:dc296e36;0a:a83a5514;0b:47420f00;0c:48010000;0d:f0441303;0e:97ecee33;0f:f0dde633;10:10000000;metype:5;mecount:2;medata:10003;medata:6;
>   program received signal 6,
>   thread:321e1;qaddr:366e2ad0;00:00000000;01:00000000;02:00000000;03:ffffffff;04:06000000;05:dc296e36;06:e8260b03;07:dc441303;08:00000000;09:7990ee33;0a:a83a5514;0b:47420f00;0c:48010000;0d:d0441303;0e:97ecee33;0f:f0dde633;10:10000000;metype:5;mecount:2;medata:10003;medata:6;
>   program received signal 5,
>   thread:321e1;qaddr:366e2ad0;00:00000000;01:00000000;02:00000000;03:01000000;04:ec441303;05:ffffffff;06:e8260b03;07:fc441303;08:00000000;09:7990ee33;0a:a83a5514;0b:47420f00;0c:30000000;0d:e4441303;0e:abc9e033;0f:aac9e033;10:30000040;metype:6;mecount:2;medata:1;medata:defe;
>   program received signal 5,
>   thread:321e1;qaddr:366e2ad0;00:00000000;01:00000000;02:00000000;03:01000000;04:ec441303;05:ffffffff;06:e8260b03;07:fc441303;08:00000000;09:7990ee33;0a:a83a5514;0b:47420f00;0c:30000000;0d:e4441303;0e:abc9e033;0f:aac9e033;10:30000040;metype:6;mecount:2;medata:1;medata:defe;
>   program received signal 5,
>   thread:321e1;qaddr:366e2ad0;00:00000000;01:00000000;02:00000000;03:01000000;04:ec441303;05:ffffffff;06:e8260b03;07:fc441303;08:00000000;09:7990ee33;0a:a83a5514;0b:47420f00;0c:30000000;0d:e4441303;0e:abc9e033;0f:aac9e033;10:30000040;metype:6;mecount:2;medata:1;medata:defe;
>   program received signal 5,
>   thread:321e1;qaddr:366e2ad0;00:00000000;01:00000000;02:00000000;03:01000000;04:ec441303;05:ffffffff;06:e8260b03;07:fc441303;08:00000000;09:7990ee33;0a:a83a5514;0b:47420f00;0c:30000000;0d:e4441303;0e:abc9e033;0f:aac9e033;10:30000040;metype:6;mecount:2;medata:1;medata:defe;
>   hit maximum number of consecutive signals, stopping Run ended.

where

> TestPage.qml:727

is `legend.visible`

Why does this code work in the simulator but fails on a real device?